# ODBC Driver 13 for Raspbian

Tags: python, database, azure, pyodbc

Today I try to connect to the database in Microsoft Azure cloud. I've already read in the Internet that I should use an ODBC Driver. My question is: is ODBC supported by Raspbian? I couldn't find any proper method to implement it in Raspbian. Has somebody dealt with that problem? I still get an error as follows

```
pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

Comment: Do you know how to install msodbcsql in Raspbian? I still get an error: 

       Unable to locate package msodbcsql

Comment: Do you check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-driver-manager)?

Comment: Based on my understanding, Raspbin is also a kind of linux, the link should work for you.

Comment: I've already tried it and it doesn't work